# I need white color like transparent color

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem.
I have this program that makes the black color transparent.

```
src=imread("0.jpg", 1);
cvtColor(src,tmp,CV_BGR2GRAY);  
threshold(tmp,alpha,100,255,THRESH_BINARY);         
Mat rgb[3];     
split(src,rgb);

Mat rgba[4]={rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2],alpha};   
merge(rgba,4,dst);          
imwrite("1.png",dst);
```

And his input and output is:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPkXg.jpg - input
2. [Transparent background with white places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdoFC.png) - output

But I don't want black color transparent, I want that white is transparent.
But I can not figure it out.
Could you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: try `threshold(tmp,alpha,100,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);`

Comment: It works, thanks. :)

Comment: glad to help,you can delete your answer

Comment: @sturkmen And you could recast your answer as an answer.

Comment: How to get those 10 points, I could write put another question?

Answer (score 2):

```
src=imread("0.jpg", 1);
cvtColor(src,tmp,CV_BGR2GRAY);  
threshold(tmp,alpha,100,255,THRESH_BINARY_INV);        
Mat rgb[3];     
split(src,rgb);

Mat rgba[4]={rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2],alpha};   
merge(rgba,4,dst);          
imwrite("1.png",dst);
```

If we choose THRESH_BINARY_INV instead of THRESH_BINARY. 
Output is: [Black background with some transparent places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8WhP.png).
This was the whole problem and now is solved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: And how to get 10 points, I want to ask another question. Thank you for answer.